# Irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Does there exist an irreducible polynomial over a field K  with two roots $a,b$
and $k\in K$ such that $a=b+k$ ?

This can't happen if K is of characteristic $0$ , but can it happen if K is of characteristic greater that $0$?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yes. The standard example is $x^p - x - a$ over a field of characteristic $p$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory for details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer